# How to do the same operation as OPENXML but with the nodes() method in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

In SQL Server, what would be the equivalent of this OPENXML command but using the nodes() method?

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML = '<data><Row><Name>Name A</Name><Type>T1</Type></Row><Row><Name>Name B</Name><Type>T2</Type></Row></Data>'

DECLARE @ID INT

EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @ID OUTPUT, @MyXML

SELECT
    [Value] AS 'Value',
    [Type] AS 'Type'
INTO #temp1
FROM OPENXML (@ID, '/Data/Row', 2)
WITH (
    [Value] NVARCHAR(100)
    [Type] NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

This is as far as I managed to get:

```
SELECT
    aaa.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS 'Value'
INTO #temp1
FROM @MyXML.nodes('/Data/Row') AS T(aaa)
```

I could not figure out how to populate the [Type] field.

#temp1 should basically have 2 rows with the Name and Type columns.  Each row would be:

```
Name A | T1
Name B | T2
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added a sample of @MyXML and the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you thought `.` would get you results from the `Name` node, that just gets you the whole outer `Row` node. You need `(Name/text())[1]` instead. And select another column for the `Type` node.

```sql
SELECT
    x1.datarow.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Value,
    x1.datarow.value('(Type/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Type
FROM @MyXML.nodes('/Data/Row') AS x1(datarow);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/WmnM9PJL)